# Creating an google calendar event with gadget using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-gadget, google-api-php-client

I have a working script which is creating events in my google calendar - using google-api-php-client. I'm trying to add a **gadget** to each event it creates with the following code:

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";

require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php";

define('CLIENT_ID', 'xxx...');

define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME', 'xxx...');

define('KEY_FILE', 'xxx...');

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName("WEB ACCTION");

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,'xxx...',$key));

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

$event = new Google_Event();

$event->setSummary($variable1);

$event->setLocation($variable2 . ", " . $variable3);

$start = new Google_EventDateTime();

$start->setDateTime(date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($variable4) + $time_offset));

$event->setStart($start);

$end = new Google_EventDateTime();

$end->setDateTime(date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($variable5) + $time_offset));

$event->setEnd($end);

//The not working section

//$gadget = new Google_EventGadget();           
//$gadget->setIconLink('xxx...');
//$gadget->setTitle('xxx...');
//$gadget->setHeight('xxx...');
//$gadget->setWidth('xxx...');
//$gadget->setLink('xxx...');
//$gadget->setType('xxx...');
//$gadget->setDisplay('xxx...');
//$event->setGadget($gadget);

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert($g_calendar , $event);
```

Unfortunately - I can not make it work and I was not able to find any information about creating the gadgets with google-api-php-client. The library includes a **Google_EventGadget** class and **setGadget** function but there is no information how to use ithem. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - it occures that the google-api-php-client supports only the certified links to the gadget and its icon. It didn´t work until I used the **https://www...** links.

It works fine even though the hosting I used for tests has no security certificate.

```
$gadget->setIconLink('https://www...');

$gadget->setLink('https://www....');

$gadget->setDisplay('chip');

$gadget->setWidth('400');

$gadget->setHeight('100');

$event->setGadget($gadget);

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert($g_calendar , $event);
```

Hope it will save someone some time!